# Substract days in a filtered timeseries column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
date           number
2016-01-20       1
2016-06-21       1
2012-05-6        1
```

I know want to substract 10 days of each date, but only to those dates that are smaller than march 2014. The result should look like this:

```
date           number
2016-01-10       1
2016-06-11       1
2012-05-6
```

I tried the following command, but it simply does not change the column. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong here?

```
df[df["date"].isin(pd.date_range("2014-02-01", "2018-01-01"))]["date"] = df[df["date"].isin(pd.date_range("2014-02-01", "2018-01-01"))]["date"] - pd.Timedelta(10, "D")
```

If i just run this command:

```
df[df["date"].isin(pd.date_range("2014-02-01", "2018-01-01"))]["date"] - pd.Timedelta(10, "D")
```

It correctly gives me the substracted dates of the filtered dataframe. However, I do not know how to map these then back to the filtered original date column to replace the not-substracted dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df.date = df.date.where(df.date < '2014-03-01', df.date - pd.Timedelta(10, 'D'))
df
#         date  number
#0  2016-01-10  1
#1  2016-06-11  1
#2  2012-05-06  1
```

Or use `loc` with *boolean indexing* and *assignment*:

```
df.loc[df.date > '2014-03-01', 'date'] -= pd.Timedelta(10, 'D')

df
#         date  number
#0  2016-01-10       1
#1  2016-06-11       1
#2  2012-05-06       1
```